# What is the internal springframework class(ses) that take a property name and string value, infer the type and set it on a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I'm interested in reusing this logic for something I'm working on.

Given

```
<bean name="myBeanWithSetXyz" class="com.blah.Something/>
 <property name="xyz" value="3"/>
```

is there a spring class someplace that figures out **setXyz()** is an int, and sets it on an instance of the bean?

Or perhaps some other utility?   Yeah, I could write it myself, but I'm a fan of reuse.

Comment: I see apache beanutils has some of this functionality.

Comment: In Spring you have `BeanWrapper` interface and `BeanWrapperImpl` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectFieldAccessor and BeanWrapperImpl are your most likely candidates.

```
ConfigurablePropertyAccessor fieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor (someObject);
beanWrapper.setPropertyValue(fieldName, 
   fieldAccessor.convertForProperty(value, fieldName) );


ConfigurablePropertyAccessor beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(someObject);
beanWrapper.setPropertyValue(propertyName, 
   beanWrapper.convertForProperty(value, propertyName) );
```

Comment: note, ConfigurablePropertyAccessor is the common base class which you need.  It implements both TypeConverter (for convertForProperty) and PropertyAccessor (for setPropertyValue).

Comment: looks like beanWrapper.setPropertyValue(propertyName, value) works perfectly fine and does the conversion internally.  Thanks!